# shortcode to display nested ACF repeater fields

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, acfpro

In Wordpress, in order to display a nested repeater ACF field, I adapted a few lines in php that I insert in the archive page of post.
In the archive, the hard code runs very well and the lines created by the code are displayed as expected.
I need to use this code via Elementor. To do that, I need to create a shortcode.
I created a shortcode with the code.
Nothing runs good, nothing is displayed, even when I desactive Elementor
Can you, please, help me,
Bruno

Here is the code:

```
function acf2repeaters_ingredients_function() {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // check for rows (parent repeater)
        if( have_rows('en-tete_ingredients') ): ?>
            <div id="en-tete_ingredients">
                <?php // loop through rows (parent repeater) 
                while( have_rows('ingredients') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <div>
                        <h3><?php the_sub_field('en-tete_ingredients'); ?></h3>
                        <?php // check for rows (sub repeater)
                        if( have_rows('liste_des_ingredients') ): ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php // loop through rows (sub repeater)
                                while( have_rows('ingredients') ): the_row(); ?>
                                    <li <?php echo ' class="nombre"'; ?>><?php the_sub_field('quantite');?></li>
                                    <li <?php echo ' class="unite"'; ?>><?php the_sub_field('unite');?></li>
                                    <li <?php echo ' class="ingredient"'; ?>><?php the_sub_field('ingredient');?></li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; //if( get_sub_field('ingredients') ): ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; // while( has_sub_field('en-tete_ingredients') ): ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; // if( get_field('en-tete_ingredients') )
    endwhile; // end of the loop.
}
add_shortcode( 'acf2repeaters_ingredients', 'acf2repeaters_ingredients_function' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Remove line:  `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()`;
Remove line:  `endwhile; // end of the loop.`
Then the shortcode rocks!